# Dynamically, continously, set a cell's value according to ActiveCell's value (which is on another worksheet)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a two sheets, `Rep` and `Aux`.
I want to dynamically set `Aux!A2` to the value of the `ActiveCell`, which is on sheet `Rep`, but only if the `ActiveCell` is on column `D` of that sheet (in the range `Rep!D2:D5000`).
To top it all of I need this mechanism to run as long as the workbook is active, not just a one-shot.

**For example**: While being on sheet `Rep` I place the cursor, i.e. `ActiveCell` on cell `D2`. I expect `Aux!A2` to be set to the value of `Rep!D2`. I move the cursor to, say, `Rep!F5` and expect **nothing** to happen to `Aux!A2`, lastly, I activate cell `Rep!D7` and again, expect `Aux!A2` to get the `ActiveCell`'s value. Continue till I close the workbook.

My VBA skills are non-existent and Googling, the only thing remotely close to what I described was:

```
Sub Macro1()
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Sheets("Rep").Range("D2:D5000")) Is Nothing Then Sheets("Aux").Range("A2").Value = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

Which fails completely.

Comment: I would recommend looking into capturing values on sheet change.  You're new to VBA, so it will be a bit of reading, but hopefully this will send you in the correct direction.  This would be a worksheet change-event based on sheet change.  The overall goal is to A) have your Sheets("Rep") value selected, B) if-statement to check if the activecell.column=4 (D=4) then copy the activecell.value as "something", C) apply the activecell.value into the formula on your Sheets("Aux").  Overall, i can help you fix coding, but Stack Overflow does not typically code for people.

Comment: First of all, thanks.
Second, after I figured how to capture a cell change and transfer that change to another cell... what is the area/keyword to look for about making it persistent as long as the workbook is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the code of the "Rep" worksheet.  Triggers anytime a cell is selected on that sheet, if the cell is in column 4 (D) then it sets the value of the cell on Aux to match.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aux").Cells(2, 1).value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT:  In response to comments.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
End Sub
```

This subroutine is an event that exists on every worksheet.  Any time a selection changes it will run any code you put in it.  The "ByVal Target as Excel.Range" part is saying it's giving you a copy of the target range being selected, because you could select more then one cell.

```
If Target.Column = 4 Then
end if
```

This is an If Block.  If the condition is true, any code between the "Then" and the "End If" will execute.  The condition is if the target's column is 4 in this case.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aux").Cells(2, 1).value = Target.Value
```

This sets the cell at row 2 column 1 value to match the value of the target that was selected.

Now that I think about it I wonder what this code will do if you select a range of cells.....

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.  
Now all that's left for me is to figure out what all this code actually means, like Cyril suggested in a comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, really does help me try to start and understand (I've got a long way to go, VBA-wise).  
As for selecting a range, gave it a try, seems like it "selects" the first value of the range.